# Made a boot USB, loads into GRUB?

Tags: boot, usb, ssd

I recently purchased a new computer with a SSD inside, no installs currently on it. I created the bootable USB and plugged it in, making sure that it boots from the USB in the BIOS.

It loads the GRUB command prompt and I have attempted to Google how to actually download it onto my new SSD. Following some guides online, using the `ls (hdx)` command brings me to no drive being recognized.

Is my SSD bad or am I just really lost?

Answer (score 0):

If you are being booted into the Grub2 commandline automatically then it means your flashdrive is having technical issues. You'll need to set it up again. If you run into the same issue again, try a different usb-creator tool, different flashdrive, or try using a DVD instead.

If you are intentionally booting into the Grub2 commandline, and wish to see a list of your drives from Grub2, you can use the command:

> ls

[screenshot of ls command in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkQVS.png)